# How to filter this data using Dictionary/List<Document>?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, document

I need some help here for my code.

I wrote this code.

```
List<Document> doc = SystemOperationManager.GetSalesByMemberLucene(ConfigurationManager.GetIndexPath(), memberId).ToList();

Dictionary<string, Department> _allDepartments = DepartmentManager.GetAll().ToDictionary(s => s.Id.ToString(), s => s);
Dictionary<string, User> _allUsers = UserManager.GetAll().ToDictionary(s => s.Id.ToString(), s => s);
Dictionary<string, Product> _allProducts = ProductManager.GetAll().Where(x => x.CustomType == 2).ToDictionary(s => s.Id.ToString(), s => s);

List<SystemOperation> so = doc.Select(s => new SystemOperation
{
    ObjStylist = s.Get("ObjStylist") != null ? _allUsers[s.Get("ObjStylist")] : null,
    ObjDepartment = s.Get("ObjDepartment") != null ? _allDepartments[s.Get("ObjDepartment")] : null,
    ObjProduct = s.Get("ObjProduct") != null ? _allProducts[s.Get("ObjProduct")] : null
    //TotalPointsCollected = decimal.Parse(s.Get("TotalPointsCollected")),
    //PointsAccumulated = decimal.Parse(s.Get("PointsAccumulated"))
}).ToList();

_result = so;
rgList.DataSource = _result;
rgList.DataBind();
```

when I run the code it say it has this error.

An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Anyone can help me fix it?

Comment: Please provide the complete exception WITH stacktrace or at least the line where this error occured.

Comment: you have to check for each dictionary lookup `if(yourdictionary.ConatiansKey("yourkey"))`....

Comment: What kind of class is `SystemOperation`? What does it method `Get` do and what does it return?

Comment: @MilenPavlov: Have to? No he doesn't. Perhaps all this data is coming from a database without a solid reference integrity. Using `ContainsKey` might hide the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given the exception you mentioned i suspect the calls to the dictionaries should be checked before you try to access them, so instead of

```
_allUsers[s.Get("ObjStylist")]
```

you could try

```
_allUsers.ContainsKey(s.Get("ObjStylist")) ? _allUsers[s.Get("ObjStylist")] : null
```

the same goes for `_allDepartments[s.Get("ObjDepartment")]` and `_allProducts[s.Get("ObjProduct")]`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you're trying to lookup for a key that doesn't exists in the dictionary. For example: `_allUsers[s.Get("ObjStylist")]`  if `s.Get("ObjStylist")` contains a nonexisting key, you'll get this error.

Therefor a `TryGetValue()` method of a dictionary is very usefull, because you're only looking up the key ones *(instead of using `Contains()` and `dict[key]`)*

**You could create a lookup function which returns the value is it exists (this generic function will work on all dictionaries)**

*(this example is not tested and might need some tweaks)*

```
private T LookupData<T>(Dictionary<string, T> dict, string key)
{
    if(key == null)
        return null;

    T result;

    if(dict.TryGetValue(key, out result))
        return result;
    else
        return null;

}



List<Document> doc = SystemOperationManager.GetSalesByMemberLucene(ConfigurationManager.GetIndexPath(), memberId).ToList();

Dictionary<string, Department> _allDepartments = DepartmentManager.GetAll().ToDictionary(s => s.Id.ToString(), s => s);
Dictionary<string, User> _allUsers = UserManager.GetAll().ToDictionary(s => s.Id.ToString(), s => s);
Dictionary<string, Product> _allProducts = ProductManager.GetAll().Where(x => x.CustomType == 2).ToDictionary(s => s.Id.ToString(), s => s);

List<SystemOperation> so = doc.Select(s => new SystemOperation
{
    ObjStylist = LookupData<User>(_allUsers, s.Get("ObjStylist")),
    ObjDepartment = LookupData<Department>(_allDepartments, s.Get("ObjDepartment")),
    ObjProduct = LookupData<Product>(_allProducts, s.Get("ObjProduct"))
    //TotalPointsCollected = decimal.Parse(s.Get("TotalPointsCollected")),
    //PointsAccumulated = decimal.Parse(s.Get("PointsAccumulated"))
}).ToList();

_result = so;
rgList.DataSource = _result;
rgList.DataBind();
```